Can't modify "Tagged date" metadata of an MP4 file in C# using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell
I'm working on a C# program to transfer all metadata from one MP4 file to another. I'm using the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell library to achieve this. The program successfully transfers most metadata properties. However, when I check the metadata using the mediainfo utility, I notice that the "Tagged date" property is not transferred and remains unchanged. I couldn't find this property in SystemProperties.System.*. I also tried iterating over properties containing "date" in their names and setting them to a specific date to see if "Tagged date" would change, but this did not happen.
I attempted to manually set properties related to dates to see if it would affect the "Tagged date" but without success. I also found out that this value is set by some programs when creating a video file but I still can't change its value. I also tried to search for bytes corresponding to the date via HxD, but I couldn't found it

I'v found a solution by directly modifying the byte data of the MP4 file. The following C# code demonstrates how to locate and replace the bytes associated with the "Tagged date" property in an MP4 file.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "./input.mp4";
        byte[] searchPattern = { 0x6D, 0x76, 0x68, 0x64 }; //# 'mvhd' header pattern in MP4 files

        string dateString = "2012-02-06 06:26:50"; //# example date
        byte[] replacementData = GetReplacementData(dateString);

        ReplaceBytes(filePath, searchPattern, replacementData);
    }

    static byte[] GetReplacementData(string dateString)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        long time = new DateTimeOffset(date).ToUnixTimeSeconds() + 2082844800;
        byte[] replacementData = BitConverter.GetBytes(time).Take(4).ToArray();

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(replacementData);
        }

        return replacementData;
    }

    static void ReplaceBytes(string filePath, byte[] searchPattern, byte[] replacementData)
    {
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        bool found = false;
        bool match = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.Length - 20; i++)
        {
           if (fileData[i] == searchPattern[0]) //# it matches first search byte?
           {
                for (int j = 0; j < searchPattern.Length; j++) //# also check rest for matching
                {
                    if (fileData[i + j] != searchPattern[j])
                    { match = false; break; }
                    
                    if (j == (searchPattern.Length -1)) //# if all counted bytes are matching
                    { match = true; }
                }

                if (match == true)
                {
                    found = true;
                    int offset = ( i + searchPattern.Length + 8 );
                    Array.Copy(replacementData, 0, fileData, offset, replacementData.Length);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Search pattern not found.");
            return;
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileData);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes replaced successfully.");
    }
}

